# pyinstaller comand not found in raspberry, after installing. why?

Tags: pyinstaller

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/sbm/SBC/sbc_offline $ Pyinstaller
bash: Pyinstaller: command not found
```

show the above error,

I used commands for installing pyinstaller is

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Is there any solution for it? I actually want to make package of my code in raspberry (in python), please suggest some solution for it.

Comment: It looks like the binary is lowercase, did you try `pyinstaller` instead of `Pyinstaller`?

Comment: @Dave yes i have tried, but its not working for me